# Sheets time-based triggers failing now

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

The trigger function in question opens the spreadsheet to which it is bound by calling SpreadsheetApp.getActive(). It had been working fine until the past month or so. It still works when I run it directly. What do I need to do to make it run again as a manually installed time-based trigger?
This is the error I get:

Mar 23, 2020, 8:49:44 AM    Error   Exception: Document tCFl8MBsaqYwxcGogX2B1hg is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)
at HideOldEntries(Code:230:44)

Here is the code fragment:

```
function HideOldEntries() {
  const sheets = ['english','shengde','xingde','peide'];
  const now = new Date();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    //line:230
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
    ...
  }
}
```

Project Triggers:
[image: Project Triggers]

Edit Trigger:
[image: Edit Trigger]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Could you please provide some more information on your trigger?

Comment: The trigger was created manually from the UI. See the attached screen captures in the original post.

Comment: Check the permissions of the Sheet, it sounds like an issue with the person trying to run the line not having read access. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23923179/11551468) for more information.

Comment: Sharing permission is Anyone with link, and the trigger is running as me the owner anyway. So when I deleted the trigger and added it again now it works. I should have tried this first.

Comment: Awesome, I'll add this as an answer for future users.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*The Sheet permissions and the permissions that the trigger is running on mismatch.*

#### Fix:

Double check the permissions of the Sheet as the person who is trying to run the code will not have access.

The other option is the user in which the trigger is being run as does not have the permission either. Delete and re-setup this trigger to fix.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Share files from Google Drive - Computer - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en&ref_topic=7000947)